# two questionnaires, two variables, two populations but one correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, structural-equation-modeling

I have two variable in my research. the first is managers commitment & the second is personnel satisfaction. so we have two population & two questionnaire, one for managers & the other with "different" questions for personnel. moreover the number of managers is different from the number of personnel. how can I calculate correlation & regression between these two population as one population with two variable?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

To calculate either correlation or regression in respect of managers' commitment and personnel satisfaction, you need a dataset that not only has the same number of each variable but also pairs the variables in a meaningful way.  How best to pair the variables will depend on the circumstances and on your research hypothesis.  However, one obvious approach would be to pair a measure of commitment for a manager with an *average* of the measures of satisfaction for all the personnel working with (or reporting to) that manager.  Calling the first measure $x_i$ and the second $y_i$, where $i$ indexes the managers, you would then be in a position to apply standard calculation methods.

Comment: +1, a nice suggestion. A (complex) extension of this idea would be to use a multi-level model: that is, a model where the relationship between manager-level information and personnel-level information is estimated taking into consideration the fact that one or more personnel may "belong" to the same manager. Thus you could explicitly account for the similarities (or non-independence) of responses of the different personnel working for the same manager.